# Angularjs llamar a funcion desde otra funcion

Tags: angularjs

tengo una duda con respecto a angularjs

Supongamos que tengo dos factory

```html
var Contact = function() {
 
  return ["1234"];
};
app.factory("Contact", Contact);

var UserService = function(Contact) {
  var users = ["Peter", "Daniel", "Nina"];

  return {
    all: function() {
      return users;
    },
    first: function() {
      return Contact;
    }
  };
};

app.factory("UserService", UserService);
```

Resulta que esto me funciona pero yo quiero declarar la variable Contact dentro del factory

```
var UserService = function() {

Contact = new Contact;
```

por ejemplo
pero esto no me funciona. Como puedo llamar desde dentro del factory a otro factory?

Gracias

Comment: Las llamadas a otros componentes, ya sean factories, services, etc.. se hacen mediante inyección de dependencia, no mediante instanciación =)

Comment: Como puedo inyectar una dependencia que dependa de una variable?

Comment: Lo que quieres es pasar un parámetro a las funciones creadas dentro de los factories? No entiendo eso de _inyectar una dependencia dependiente de una variable_ =/

Comment: Lo he refactado fatal .

Comment: Lo que quería decir, es que digamos que desde el Userservice podria recibir diferentes factory de contact que dependerá de una variable que se encuentra en el videoservice. Digamos que el videoservice tiene una variable con.valor contactocompleto entonces este llamará al factory del contactAll , por el contrario llamará al factory Contact. Se que suena raro pero digamos que tengo diferentes factory que podría llamar dependiendo de esa variable.

Comment: Pero como no puedo instanciarlos desde el userservice (dentro)como o donde podría hacer esa condición para saber que tipo de factory llamar

Comment: Personalmente, y como lo visualizo la forma en que estas trabajando con los factories es incorrecta, ya que en resumen estas utilizando 4 services para obtener datos completos o no de un usuario?

Comment: En realidad necesito representar lo que antes expliqué. En realidad es algo mas complicado y he resumido el codigo a un ejemplo absurdo y sin sentido, lo que quiero representar no son usuarios y contactos.

Comment: Quiero poder desde un factory llamar a otros factory dependiendo de un valor que será dinámico y dependerá de lo que el usuario seleccione. En otras palabras es una variable que contenga el factory seleccionado.